How do I offset the joint values in ros2_control by a multiple/divisible to account for the gearboxes on my real actuators?
I'm using ros2_control to send connect moveit 2 and my real robot together, however on my real robot, the motors attached to joints are connected to gearboxes, and I cannot seem to find a way to just divide the joint values that moveit is receiving in ros2 control or in moveit. I've tried using the transmission interface, but it seems like it does nothing. I get no error messages or any type of output from the plugin when I use it in my ros2_control Urdf, which will be attached.
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>odrive_ros2_control_plugin/ODriveHardwareInterface</plugin>
            <param name="can">can0</param>
        </hardware>
        
        <joint name="Revolute4">
            <param name="node_id">0</param>
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="Revolute5">
            <param name="node_id">1</param>
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>

        <transmission name="transmission1">
            <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
            <actuator name="actuator1" role="actuator1"/>
            <joint name="Revolute4" role="Revolute4">
            <mechanical_reduction>5.0</mechanical_reduction>
            <offset>0.0</offset>
            </joint>
        </transmission>

        <transmission name="transmission2">
            <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
            <actuator name="actuator2" role="actuator2"/>
            <joint name="Revolute5" role="Revolute5">
            <mechanical_reduction>6.0</mechanical_reduction>
            <offset>0.0</offset>
            </joint>
        </transmission>

    </ros2_control>
</xacro:macro>

Unfortunately I am not able to account for this in the motor controllers themselves.. Any help would be appreciated

You need to adapt your hardware component to make use of the transmission interface. I wrote some documentation about that recently, but it is not merged yet.
See also example_8 on how to use a simple transmission interface exactly doing what you want to achieve.
